# Print variable 'string value' instead of value

Tags: python, dictionary, variables, dynamic

```
lst = [1,2]
x = lst 
print(x) #this will print the value of x, which is [1,2]
```

Is there anyway that I can print 'lst' as a string, isntead of the value [1,2] ?

I do need this a I am creating a dynamic python dictionary where python dict key is a dynamic 'string' , in my case I should have dict[lst] where lst is the key, for example.

Comment: `print(str(x))`?

Comment: You don't need to use a string, you can use a tuple instead: `dict[tuple(lst)]`.

Comment: The object bound to `x` and `lst` has no idea it is bound to either name; the mapping is unidirectional. You can't get either name from the object itself, short of using the `inspect` module to analyze the source code itself.

Comment: If you care about the name of the variable, it should be a key in some other `dict` instead.

Answer (score 0):

so, I found a python library called varname, in which it has a function of "nameof()" and this function returns the object name, not value.

```
!pip install varname
from varname import nameof 

lst = [1,2]
x = nameof(lst) 
print(x) #this will print the string 'lst'
```